# Invoke the Command line with a Netbeans plugin

Tags: plugins, netbeans, command-line, netbeans-plugins

i am developing a Netbeans Plugin where i need to invoke a command(windows bath file) which can be executed with the command prompt. is there a way to invoke that batch file from the Netbeans plugin?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Runtime.exec or alternatively you can have a look at the [NetBeans Developer FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansDeveloperFAQ) specifically the page on [External Processes](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqOutputWindowExternalProcess) I would think.